# format Timestamp() in aws glue and write to postgres table

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm creating a POC for some aws glue jobs that will take a file from s3, convert the schema and load into a postgres database. If I make all the columns `string` the data will read in correctly. However, the data needs to be read in with `load_dt` as a `timestamp`. When I do that I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while calling o 120.pyWriteDynamicFrame. ERROR: null value column load_dt" of relation "t002_stg" violates not-null constraint.
```

Read in code:

```
AmazonS3_node12345 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"quoteChar": '"', "withHeader": True, "separator": "|"},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="csv",
    connection_options={
        "paths": ["s3://dedicated_drop_folder/decrypted/product_lookups.csv"],
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node12345",
)

# Script generated for node Change Schema
ChangeSchema_node12345 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=AmazonS3_node12345,
    mappings=[
        ("product_name", "string", "product_name", "string"),
        ("pd_parent_name", "string", "pd_parent_name", "string"),
        ("LAST_LOAD_DT", "string", "LOAD_DT", "timestamp"),
        ("DATA_SRC_NM", "string", "DATA_SRC_NM", "string"),
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ChangeSchema_node12345",
)

# Script generated for node PostgreSQL
PostgreSQL_node12345 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    frame=ChangeSchema_node12345,
    database="dev_testing",
    table_name="crm_pricing_lk_stg",
    transformation_ctx="PostgreSQL_node12345",
)

 

job.commit()
```

I know I can call `toDF()` to put it in pyspark and make the call with `df = df.withColumn("load_dt", to_timestamp("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))`
then put back in dynamic_frame but that seems to be clunky. There's only two records in the csv file so I know I have a timestamp there.

Comment: Most probably the data in `load_dt` column is not in the desired format - pyspark `to_timestamp` function returns null if it can't parse.

Comment: If I convert to pyspark and use `to_timestamp` and convert back, it works. It's just seems really clunkly. Is there a way to set the format using `dynamic_frame`?